# Is there any way to store reference of member object 'A' of a class inside another member object 'B' of the same class?

Tags: c++, oop, reference, c++17, entity-component-system

I can't access/modify the member object of wrapper class by another member object of the same class.

Basically, I have a transform object and collider object inside a gameobject and I wish to access the transform of parent gameobject from inside the collider object and modify it.

```
struct Transform{
   //some members
};

class Collider{
  //some members
  Transform *transform;
  Collider(/*somethings*/, Transform* _transform):transform(_transform){
     //some things
  }

  //some method to check collision and update transform of gameobject
};

class GameObject{
   //some other components
   Transform transform;
   Collider collider;

   GameObject(Transform transform) : collider(/*some default values*/, &(this->transform)){
      //initializing 
   }
};

int main(){
   // some code
  
   for(int i=0; i<10<i++){
      GameObject quad(Transform(/*params*/));
      quads.push_back(quad);
   }

   // some other code
}
```

I tried other methods achieve this but everything except the transform will initialize to correct value.
The closest I have came for correct initialization is by storing an alias of transform in collider which I have initialized by dereferencing the pointer passed from the gameobject. But this won't work while updating the values.

Comment: The compiler-generated copy constructor and assignment operator won't work in this setup; when you do `GameObject b = a;` you end up with `b.collider` storing a pointer to `a.transform`. This is exactly what happens in `quads.push_back(quad);`, with the additional wrinkle that `quad` goes out of scope and is destroyed soon after, leaving `quads.back().collder.transform` a dangling pointer. To make this arrangement work, you need to write a copy/move constructor and assignment operator for `GameObject`, to ensure that its `collider` member stores a pointer to its sibling `transform`.

Comment: Thanks for spotting the problem.. Only solution I now came up to solve this issue for now is by creating  a new component on a block of memory that only stores a certain component and storing the component's reference on respective gameobject,  which I think a most basic entity component system would do. I may be wrong but this works fine. Plus, this allowed for separately processing each component independently.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is using `std::shared_ptr<T>` instead of raw pointer.

```cpp
class Collider {
public:
  Collider(std::shared_ptr<Transform> _transform):transform(_transform){
  }
private:
  std::shared_ptr<Transform> transform;
};

class GameObject {
public:
   GameObject(std::shared_ptr<Transform> transform) : collider(transform) {
   }
private:
   std::shared_ptr<Transform> transform;
   Collider collider;
};
```

In this case `Collider` and `GameObject` will share the ownership over `Transform` instance and a default generated copy/move constructor/assignment will will give you necessary functionality.

On the other hand if you want not to share ownership, you can put `Transform` instance into `Collider` and make it accessible to `GameObject` with getter function.

Everything depends on the design (it's pretty hard to me understand it from small part of code).

Comment: That won't compile. You attempt to pass `Transform` where `std::shared_ptr<Transform>` is expected.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, sure, my bad. Thanks for noticing it.